# Finding expected number of returns of a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, markov-chains

> Consider the discrete time Markov chain with the following transition graph: [image]
>
> Let $N(y)$ be the total number of visits to the state $y$, eventually excluding $X_0$. In symbols, $$N(y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{X_n = y}.$$ $(a)$ Calculate $E_3[N(3)].$ 
>   $(b)$ Calculate $E_4[N(4)].$

I feel quite confident that, for $(b)$, $E_4[N(4)] = \infty$, since the set $\left\{4,5\right\}$ is closed and irreducible. However, I'm unsure how to find the precise expectation $E_3[N(3)]$.

Of course, beginning at $3$, we have with probability $5/8$ that we never return to $3$ again. However, even assuming we go to $1$ or $2$, we will eventually end back at $3$ where we again have a $5/8$ probability of going to $4$ or $5$ and, thus, never returning to $3$ again.

I suppose we really want to know the expected number of times we return to $3$ without going to $4$ or $5$. How can I go about finding this number?

*edit:* I now believe I know the general idea: to find $E_3[N(3)]$ we must find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p^{(n)}(3,3)$, where $p^{(n)}(3,3)$ is the n-step probability matrix for the chain. I'm not sure we ever learned a trick/formula to calculate this sum, however - what is a good way to go about this?

Comment: I think it is easier to just use your original observation "of course, beginning at 3, we have with probability 5/8 that we never return to 3 again."  And also the probability of returning again is 3/8 (since if you go to 1 or 2 you will definitely get back to 3 at some point).  So you can sample the chain every time you are on 3.  Similarly, how many times (on average) do you flip a biased coin before you get HEADS?

Comment: @Michael Well for an unbiased coin, you'd flip it $\frac{1}{1 - 1/2}$ = $2$ times before you expect to flip a heads - does this mean, for this example, that you'll return to $3$ $\frac{1}{1 - 3/8} = 8/5$ times before you're expected to reach either $4$ or $5$ (meaning $E_3[N(3)] = 8/5$)?

Comment: That’s right. An equivalent approach is to replace the class $\{4,5\}$ with a single absorbing state and then compute the fundamental matrix $N=\sum_{k=0}^\infty Q^k=(I-Q)^{-1}$, where $Q$ is the upper-left $3\times3$ submatrix containing only the transient states. The $(i,j)$-th entry of this matrix is the expected number of times the system is in state $j$ before being absorbed (i.e., before entering the $\{4,5\}$ class, never to return), given that it started in state $i$.

Comment: @amd interesting - I wasn't aware you could do this. Thank you so much!

Comment: It’s overkill for this problem, but a useful technique to know when the transitions aren’t quite so simple to untangle. In the general, you’ll end up with a system of linear equations, solving which is equivalent to computing $N$.